# Problem: run-as: Package is not an application

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm working on an sdk (some one else's) as base for a project.
I can run the project on my android device without problems.

So tried to access the app's database for debugging purposes so I ran this command:

run-as car.cn.sample

but then I get the error
run-as: Package 'car.cn.sample' is not an application

Its not that I am typing the name wrong because in that case I get
run-as: Package 'aa' is unknown

And I dont think that its because its not debuggable either becuse if I try the run-as command on not debuggable apps I get
run-as: Package 'com.android.providers.media' is not debuggable

but for my app it says that is not an application.
am I missing something in graddle or something?

Or is there other way that I can access the app's database in order to debug?

Thanks